# Generar ruta con parámetros en plantilla de Symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony2, inspinia

Tengo un botón que redirije a otra pagina, la cosa es que estoy con INSPINIA y en el código tengo puesto que para la pagina que estoy mostrando sea necesario poner el id de otra pagina, ¿Cómo puedo conseguirlo?:

Código de la plantilla:

```
    <a href="{{ path('asistentes_index/{id}') }}"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label">Asistentes</span></a>
</li>
```

Código condicional (php):

```
    /**
     * Creates a new asistente entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new/{idEvento}", name="asistentes_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request, $idEvento)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $evento = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Evento')->find($idEvento);
        $asistente = new Asistente();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\AsistenteType', $asistente);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();


        if(!$evento) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Evento no existe');
        }


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            return $this->redirectToRoute('asistentes_show', array('id' => $asistente->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('asistentes/new.html.twig', array(
            'asistente' => $asistente,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'evento' => $evento,
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para generar URL o PATH con parámetros, pasa como segundo parámetro de la función un objeto plano (json) cuyos indices correspondan con los parámetros de la url. Por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
<a href="{{ path('asistentes_new', {'idEvento': evento.id}) }}"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label">Asistentes</span></a>
```

Ten en cuenta que para generar rutas en la vista, no debes usar la url sino el nombre de la ruta, en tu caso `asistentes_new`